# Custom Wordpress User Type

Tags: wordpress

I want to create custom user type in wordpress. For eaxpmle there are 'Editor','Author', etc.. I want to create my own type; like say 'Developer' with particular set of access level.
 Is that possible? I am a newbie, so a little direction or suggestions will really be help.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use this, add the code below to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_role('developer', 'Developer', array(
    'read' => true,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => true,
));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Flame Trap. Perfect.